# How do I edit my category headers (h1) in WooCommerce without changing the category name?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I’m using WooCommerce (and a child theme) for Shoptimized.

For SEO purposes, I’m trying to add some keywords before my h1 title in my category page – yet I cannot figure out how to do it. I’ve looked everywhere, including in the archive-product.php file.

This was the code I changed in there, but it doesn’t make a difference:

```
<?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title">Buy Cheap <?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?> Online</h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Any suggestions on how to add the keywords before and after the category header for my category pages?

This is the webpage URL: https://moroccankart.com/throw-blankets/

Comment: could you put what you have and what kind of html are you expecting?

Comment: @FernandoUrban just added a link to the page. I just want to manipulate the H1 with some text before & after the automated Wordpress output - that's it.

Answer (score 0):

What file is being used when viewing the Throw Blankets Page?

You can install a plugin called What Template Am I Viewing. https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-template-file-am-i-viewing/. The plugin works with the  version (5.2.4) of WordPress. The plugin will display a path to the file being used. The path will be displayed in the WP-Admin bar across the top. See the plugin page for screenshots.

You can also look for a category hook. Depending on the hook, you can get pretty creative. https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/

Some themes (parent and child) have a folder called "WooCommerce" inside. This folder contains WooCommerce template files. Look in the /wp-content/themes/your-theme/ and look for a WooCommerce folder. You might have an archive-product.php file inside or something that is being used.

Comment: /plugins/woocommerce/templates/taxonomy-product_cat.php is being used. In there is just a tiny reference to archive-product.php. My theme does not have a WooCommerce folder, I even tried creating one with a modified archive-product.php to no avail.

Any other suggestions?